# JPA counting its subclass for one to many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, count, one-to-many, jpql

I am using JPA for my project and I would like to know that there is any way to count its subclass for one to many relationship. For example, let's say there is an order class that has multiple items and I need to display a list of orders.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Order {
    ...
    @Id
    private Long orderId;
    @OneToMany
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
}
```

For the list, I need to display how many items are ordered and how many items are canceled. So, I added functions such that

```
    @OneToMany
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
    ...
    public Long countOrderedItems() {
        Long count = 0;
        orderItems.forEach(orderItem -> {
            if(orderItem.getStatus().equals(Status.ORDERED)){
                count++;
            }
        });
        return count;
    }
    public Long countCancelItems() {
        Long count = 0;
        orderItems.forEach(orderItem -> {
            if(orderItem.getStatus().equals(Status.CANCEL)){
                count++;
            }
        });
        return count;
    }
```

However, this looks inefficient and I want to get these two values directly when I get data from repository like:

```
@Query("SELECT o, (SELECT COUNT(oi) FROM OrderItem oi WHERE oi.Order.orderId = o.orderId AND oi.status = 'ORDERED') FROM Order o");
```

But, I know this is not correct JPQL and I would like to know how to get these values efficiently in JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JPA 2.1 feature JOIN ON

```
select o, count(io), count(io2) from Order o 
left join o.irderItem oi on oi.status = 'ORDERED'
left join o.irderItem ui on ui.status = 'CANCELED'
group by s
```

> The join condition used for a join comes from the mapping's join columns. This means that the JPQL user is normally free from having to know how every relationship is joined. In some cases it is desirable to append additional conditions to the join condition, normally in the case of outer joins. This can be done through the ON clause.

Comment: I think this isn't violated JPQL so it looks working fine. However, I don't know how to map `count(io)` to a field. If I add a member variable `numberOfOrderedItems` to Order class then how can I map it? Because I tried it and it showed 'Unknown column 'order0_.number_of_ordered_items' in 'field list''

Comment: It cannot be mapped into entity. Untyped query return list will contain Object[]{Order, int, int}

Comment: I finally added two fields for counting ordered and canceled status with @Transient and mapped the fields in construct function. So, my final version of JPQL is `SELECT new Order(o.orderId, ..., count(io), count(io2)) FROM Order o ...` Thank you for your help @peter

Comment: @CodeImaginer you are welcome, mark answer as correct. Yes it is possible to fill it in constructor in any type of pojo. but it cannot be mapped ad as persistent entity field.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with single join also:

HSQL:

```
select o, 
sum(case when oi.itemStatus = 'ORDERED' then 1 else 0 end), 
sum(case when oi.itemStatus = 'CANCELED' then 1 else 0 end) 
from OrderItem oi 
right outer join Order o on oi.orderId = o.id
group by o.id
```

JPA Repository:

```
@Query("select new example.springboot.jpa.custom.OrderSummary(o, " +
        "sum(case when oi.itemStatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as orderedItems, " +
        "sum(case when oi.itemStatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as canceledItems)  " +
        "from OrderItem oi right join oi.customOrder o group by o")
List<OrderSummary> findAllOrdersSummary();
```

You can find full example here:
https://github.com/abhilekhsingh041992/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/jpa/src/main/java/example/springboot/jpa/repository/OrderRepository.java